# how to update a progress bar in a pyqt5 program and the pytube library

Tags: python, pyqt5, progress-bar, pytube

I tried the method 'on_progress_callback: Optional[Callable[[Any, bytes, int], None]] = None,'

but it seems that the function that must update the progress bar runs after the download function's ending , I don't know if it's a bug in the library or it's because of me, the code is
'''

```
from pytube import YouTube


def download():            
    v_url = input('enter your url : ')
    v_location = input('enter save place : ')
    video = YouTube(v_url, video_progress)
    print("000000000000000000")
    stream = video.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4')
    for s in stream:
        print(s) 
    wanted_stream = streams.get_by_itag(input('the itag of the stream : ')
    wanted_stream.download(output_path=v_location))


def video_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    size = stream.filesize
    progress = (float(abs(size - bytes_remaining) / size)) * float(100)
    print(progress)
    #self.progressBar1.setValue(progress)

download()
```

'''
now, if you run the code above while watching the results in the terminal you will find out that the progress function actually run after the download of the video had finished.
if someone know another way to update the the progress bar by the same library that will be beautiful

Comment: You say "I tried the method `on_progress_callback`", but there's no trace of that in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much , I guess threading is the solution.

Comment: Ohh, I meant  'on_progress_callback'  parameter in the 'YouTube' function.